# Buildout and p4a.video errors

Tags: plone, buildout

I'm working on an old version of Plone (buildout for Plone 3.3.6, coming from Plone 3.1).

It includes a custom product which relies on p4a.videoembed and a few other p4a related products.  When I run 'bin/buildout' I get the following error:

```
Installing instance1.
While:
   Installing instance1.
Error: There is a version conflict.
We already have: p4a.video 1.3
but p4a.plonevideoembed 1.3 requires 'p4a.video>1.3'.
```

I checked there is no p4a.video > 1.3 in pypi so, of course it won't retrieve for a higher version of p4a.video.

Comment: I suspect these eggs were published to `http://plone4artists.org/`, but that domain is now dead (read, taken over by a domain squatter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to pin p4a.plonevideoembed to an older version. I added a [versions] section to my buildout and "pinned" p4a.plonevideoembed to an older version.

```
[versions]
p4a.plonevideoembed = 1.1
```